# Do spins in Olympic diving affect the time from the platform to the surface of the water?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, moment-of-inertia, angular-velocity

Assume that a diver performs $3$ different jumps, at the same initial speed from a platform $10m$ high (straight into the water, one spin, two spins). What is the time difference in reaching the water surface?

How do you explain in physics.

Comment: Hint: what forces could cause the fall-time to change? You need some force to oppose (or augment) gravity for this to happen.